# How to use the required attribute with its false value?

Tags: html

I want to use the required attribute with its false value.

I learned that ' The required attribute is a boolean attribute '
But How can I write and make it false ?

This question is from an assignment, it says that I must to use the required attribute with a field and the field must sill ( not required )

I know that when I want to make a field not required I should simply don't write the attribute

Do you know how can I make it ?
Thank you

Comment: "it says that I must to use the required attribute with a field and the field must sill ( not required )" that's quite unclear, could you please rephrase this part? Quoting exactly the assignment might help. "I know that when I want to make a field not required I should simply don't write the attribute" <-- This is your answer.

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes

Comment: – Kaiido Thank you. I misunderstood the assignment.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Cornelissen Thank very much for the information. Now I know what means a blooean attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The required attribute don't take any values. It simply means required="true". But let say if you need to unset it value after form submission or something. you can do it from JavaScript function removeAttribute() for selected DOM elememnt.
example:
document.getElementById("input").removeAttribute("required ");

Comment: Probably better to use the IDL attribute`.required = false`.